# Find a basis for which the matrix of the following bilinear form has the form described in Sylvester's theorem

Tags: linear-algebra, change-of-basis, bilinear-form

Let V be the vector space of real valued polynomials with degree smaller equal 3 and let $$(p,q) = \int_{-1}^{1} p(x)q(x) \,dx - 100p(0)q(0)$$

Is the bilinear form degenerate and find a basis for V in which the matrix of the bilinear form is diagonal and only has 1, -1, 0 on the diagonal.

Let $W = span \{x\}$, then the restriction of the bilinear form to W is positive definite and $ W^\perp = span\{1, x^2\}$. Now since $W \oplus W^\perp \neq V $ it would appear that the bilinear form is degenerate, this felt wrong to me, since I couldn't work out a vector apart from the 0 vector that would be in the radical, so I worked out the matrix for the bilinear form and got $$\begin{pmatrix}
-98 & 0 & \frac{2}{3} & 0\\
0 & \frac{2}{3} & 0 & \frac{2}{5}\\
\frac{2}{3} & 0 & \frac{2}{5} & 0\\
0 & \frac{2}{5} & 0 & \frac{2}{7}
\end{pmatrix}$$
which is non-degenerate, so maybe I made an error somewhere, if anyone can spot it, that would be great. I feel like I should be able to solve this without the matrix.

Comment: without any matrix, take $p(x) = x$  and $q(x) = a +bx + c x^2 + d x^3 $   and integrate $ ax +bx^2 + c x^3 + d x^4 $  on their interval  from $-1$ to $1.$  The $a,c$  disappear  and there is a relationship between $b,d$  to get result zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using your matrix, $W^\perp$  is the collection of all polynomials $$ a + bx + c x^2 + d x^3 $$
for which $$ 5b + 3d = 0.$$ No restriction on $a,c.$  Span of $1, x^2, 3x-5x^3 .$  Only trivial intersection with $W$

Indeed, the inner product of $x$ and $3x - 5 x^3$  has zeroes for constant terms. Then the integral of $3x^2 - 5 x^4,$  antiderivative $x^3 - x^5 = x^3 (1-x^2)$  which evaluates to zero at each endpoint.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I guess I was too sure, that I had $W^\perp$ right, that I kind of just assumed I'd messed up the matrix somehow and didn't bother trying to work out $W^\perp$ from the matrix, which would have immediately shown me. After the fact it seems obvious that I should have tried to use Gram-Schmidt. I guess I was expecting something simpler.